# Eclipse projects using DataNucleus Enhancer reordered by last changed date on recompile / auto-enhancement

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, datanucleus

I have a multi-module maven project in eclipse 2018-09 (using the Maven Project Builder), and every time I save a file in one of the modules **the entire project tree is being reordered during recompilation and the sorting changes** as the order of the child projects in the project tree seems to depend on when it was last compiled.

I looked everywhere to stop this behavior and have a static project order (alphabetically or based on the module order in the parent POM), but haven't found anything.

Edit: **it now seems that the behavior goes away if I disable the DataNucleus Enhancer Tool** on my one project which is using DataNucleus. So maybe it's tied to the "Auto-Enhancement" mode being active?

Edit: The Filters and Customization view of the Project Explorer:

[image: Filters and Customization view]

Q: How can I preserve the order/sorting of my projects in Eclipse, and use the DataNucleus Enhancer at the same time?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in the current version of Eclipse (you are two releases behind)? What do you mean by _project tree_? The project order shown in the _Package Explorer_ view, in the _Project Explorer_ view, in the _Java Build Path_ or ...?

Comment: Thanks @howlger I tried around a bit and it seems to only occur if I use the Datanucleus Enhancer on one of the projects, so maybe not tied directly to maven or the project explorer. If Iremove the Datanucleus Enhancer the behavior goes away. Super confusing. Let me update my question.

Comment: Could you please tell where you observe the reordering? If it is in the _Project Explorer_, please show what is in the view menu _Filters and Customization_.

Comment: @howlger please see the screenshot I added to the question. The reordering happens on the child projects if I select hierarchical project structure in the Project Explorer options.